# Datagridview filtering by TextBox or CheckBox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1

Dim socketz As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP)
Dim bytedata(4096) As Byte
Dim myip As IPAddress
Dim started As Boolean = True
Dim sizediff As Size
Dim formloaded As Boolean = False
Dim FilterIPAddress As New IPAddress(0)
Dim FilterIP As Boolean
Dim mycomputerconnections() As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface

'datagridview1 Update stuff
Dim stringz As String = ""
Dim Typez As String = ""
Dim ipfrom As IPAddress
Dim ipto As IPAddress
Dim destinationport As String = ""
Dim sourceport As String = ""

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sizediff.Height = Me.Height - DataGridView1.Height
    sizediff.Width = Me.Width - DataGridView1.Width
    formloaded = True

    mycomputerconnections = Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces

    For i = 0 To mycomputerconnections.Length - 1
        Combobox1.Items.Add(mycomputerconnections(i).Name)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub OnReceive(ByVal asyncresult As IAsyncResult)
    If started = True Then
        'Get Length of packet (including header)
        Dim readlength As UInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(bytedata, 2), 0)
        sourceport = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(bytedata, 22), 0)
        destinationport = BitConverter.ToUInt16(Byteswap(bytedata, 24), 0)

        'Get Protocol Type
        If bytedata(9) = 6 Then
            Typez = "TCP"
        ElseIf bytedata(9) = 17 Then
            Typez = "UDP"
        Else
            Typez = "???"
        End If

        'Get IP from and to
        ipfrom = New IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytedata, 12))
        ipto = New IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytedata, 16))

        'If this is a packet to/from me and not from myself then...
        If (ipfrom.Equals(myip) = True Or ipto.Equals(myip) = True) And ipto.Equals(ipfrom) = False Then
            If FilterIP = False Or (FilterIP = True And (FilterIPAddress.Equals(ipfrom) Or FilterIPAddress.Equals(ipto))) Then
                'Fix data
                stringz = ""
                For i = 26 To readlength - 1
                    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(Chr(bytedata(i))) = True Then
                        stringz = stringz & Chr(bytedata(i))
                    Else
                        stringz = stringz & "."
                    End If
                Next

                'Put data to DataGridView, since it's on a different thread now, invoke it
                DataGridView1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf datagridview1Update))
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Restart the Receiving
    socketz.BeginReceive(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview1Update()
    'Remove rows if there are too many
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 9 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    End If

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(0).Value = ipfrom.ToString 'From Column, size at 125
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(1).Value = ipto.ToString  'To Column, size at 125
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(2).Value = destinationport.ToString
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(3).Value = sourceport.ToString
End Sub

Private Function Byteswap(ByVal bytez() As Byte, ByVal index As UInteger)
    Dim result(1) As Byte
    result(0) = bytez(index + 1)
    result(1) = bytez(index)
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If started = True Then
        Button1.Text = "Start"
        started = False
    Else
        Button1.Text = "Stop"
        started = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If formloaded = True Then
        DataGridView1.Size = Me.Size - sizediff
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    For i = 0 To mycomputerconnections(Combobox1.SelectedIndex).GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses.Count - 1
        If mycomputerconnections(Combobox1.SelectedIndex).GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses(i).Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            myip = mycomputerconnections(Combobox1.SelectedIndex).GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses(i).Address
            BindSocket()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BindSocket()
    Try
        socketz.Bind(New IPEndPoint(myip, 0))
        socketz.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, True)
        Dim bytrue() As Byte = {1, 0, 0, 0}
        Dim byout() As Byte = {1, 0, 0, 0}
        socketz.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, bytrue, byout)
        socketz.Blocking = False
        ReDim bytedata(socketz.ReceiveBufferSize)
        socketz.BeginReceive(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), Nothing)
        Combobox1.Enabled = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Combobox1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Try
End Sub

End Class


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Try
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox1.Text IsNot Nothing Then
            FilterIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
            FilterIP = True
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Else
            FilterIP = False
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        FilterIP = False
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm trying to filter my DataGridView to only show the TextBox1's value of the sourceport column.

Comment: Please fix the issues in your text!

Comment: Just browsing through your code I was sure the questions would be about sockets... Please provide a smaller example without that highlight your problem, do it is hidden by everything else.

Comment: forgot to add this, and I don't know how kwoxer:

Comment: How about storing your data in a DataTable and then using the RowFilter on the DefaultView to populate your DataGridView?